# How did Youtube implement this list control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

Youtube.com has a feature that allows you to create lists and then add videos you like to your lists.  Here are three screenshots that show how this control works.

[Click to add to list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn1ca.jpg)
[Add to a list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REgnz.jpg)
[Create and add to a new list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3Zxl.jpg)

Could anyone describe or speculate as to how they're implementing this control?  What is going on in each picture?  What technology(ies) are they using?  I'm not asking for anyone to write code samples.  Rather, can you explain what is happening here and what are they using (JavaScript, jQuery, JS framework X) so I can implement this myself.  I don't know much JavaScript but I'd like to be able to create controls like this.

Comment: It would most likely use a custom API designed for YouTube. There is actually a [YouTube developers API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/code_samples) available for use so im guessing the site is based on this.

Comment: Beyond the JS controls and CSS layout is a powerfull database desing to store lists for each users. That question is ***way too broad*** for someone who *«don't know JavaScript very much»*

Comment: I was just looking for some idea of what approach to investigate.  I can take it from there.  Downvote me all you want.

Comment: Approaches will be Ajax and a long thinking on your DB structure.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you just want to implement the interface, or the whole system of adding videos to playlists etc

Comment: I just want to learn how to implement the modal interface with the list elements and the ability to create a new list.  I understand how to do the backend database stuff.  I'm doing some research and it appears that this can be done with jQuery and Ajax as Louys alluded to.  I looked at Youtube's code and their code looks custom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube interface is built with a usage of [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/).

This particular component is [iron-dropdown](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-dropdown), which is responsible for all logic of "Modal" dialog.

Inside of this dialog, they have different custom components like `ytd-add-to-playlist-renderer`, `paper-checkbox`. These components just render HTML elements inside of the main dropdown element.